# can't login as admin or guest

Tags: login

I am relatively new to Linux, and I installed a few applications via the command line yesterday. This morning, after boot up, I coulds't login anymore, neither as administrator nor as guest. When I try <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd>+1, and try to login, it says:

```
wrong username and password
```

Another thing is that on boot up, another error appears, but it passes by too fast to read.

When I try to login on the graphical login screen (both as admin or guest) it shows 2 lines of code and returns to the graphical login screen.

Is it possible to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change your user password:

1. Reboot
2. At OS selection menu, select "Advanced options for Ubuntu" and then select the first entry that ends with "(recovery mode)"
3. At the prompt, select "root"
4. `mount -o remount,rw /`
5. `passwd [username]` to change the password

This should at least let you log in via a VT (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) so that we can further diagnose the problem if one still exists.

Comment: I could try that. however, I've got dual boot provided by windows. I only have advanced bootoptions for windows it seems.

Comment: Is this a Win 8 machine?

Comment: no windows 7. and i think i gave too few information. My password is entered correctly. when i give a wrong password on de graphical login screen it says wrong login. but when i try to log in via VT, It always says wrong username and password or wrong log in ( or something similar). and its ubuntu 12.04

Comment: well never mind. i think i'll just install ubuntu 14 over the ubuntu 12. but thanks for the help anyway(y)